# Firebase Realtime Database Value Retrieval

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am authenticating user with a mobile number. Now I want to know that if user is a first time user than it will redirect to some activity and if user previously already logged in so user can navigate to dashboard screen. ow can I solve this problem?
This is my database Snapshot.
H[image]
This is my User class.

```
public class User {
    String userName, mobile;
    List<Object> groupIds;
    public User(String userName, String mobile) {
        this.userName = userName;
        this.mobile = mobile;
        groupIds = new ArrayList<>();
        groupIds.add("group1");
    }
    public User() {}

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }
    public void setUserName(String userName) {
        this.userName = userName;
    }
    public String getMobile() {
        return mobile;
    }
    public void setMobile(String mobile) {
        this.mobile = mobile;
    }
    public List<Object> getGroupIds() {
        return groupIds;
    }
    public void setGroupIds(List<Object> groupIds) {
        this.groupIds = groupIds;
    }
}
```

In authentication success I am writing this following code :

```
   mDatabase.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    showData(dataSnapshot);
                                }
                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                                }
                            });
```

```
private void showData(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
            User uInfo = new User();
            uInfo.setUserName(ds.child("Users").child("112233").getValue(User.class).getUserName());
            uInfo.setMobile(ds.child("Users").child("112233").getValue(User.class).getMobile());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: name: " + uInfo.getMobile());
            Log.d(TAG, "showData: email: " + uInfo.getUserName());           
        }
    }
```

Comment: If user first time also he goes to dashboard or somewhere else?

Comment: If a User first time logged in then it navigate to Profile Activity to setup his/her profile. But if user have profile already then user redirected to dashboard activity.@PeterHaddad

Comment: are u using firebase authentication?

Comment: Yes with Mobile Number. @PeterHaddad

Comment: why dont u use firebase uid instead of mobile number?

Comment: In my application every user is connected with other user with their respective contact list. So I need a mobile authentication. And I am creating object of user ID only. This is a sample data so I write 112233 as ID over there

Comment: why dont you check values in user profile, if isnot set then user is new

Comment: But for that also I have to go through the values. The code is not showing result anything. @IvanVovk

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are using firebase authentication, then you can do the following:

First inside `if (task.isSuccessful()) {`, do the following:

```
boolean isNew = task.getResult().getAdditionalUserInfo().isNewUser();
```

if `isNew` returns true then the user is logging in for the first time and you can navigate to the `Profile Activity`

---

if you want the user to navigate to the dashBoard Activity, then you can check if user is null or not:

```
FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
if (user != null) {
    // User is signed in
} else {
    // No user is signed in
}
```

if user is not equal to null, then navigate to the dashboard activity else navigate to the login page.

`FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser()` will return null if you call `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().signOut();` which means if you dont sign out then it will always be not equal to null thus you will be able to navigate to dashboard activity.

Check the following for more info:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/manage-users

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/AdditionalUserInfo